# promise not working for me http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise

- I am using a promise to get my response.
- but he value is not coming in my console.
- can you tell me whats the problem.
- providing my code below

```or-tag-here
const https = require('https');
/*
 * Complete the function below.
 * Use console.log to print the result, you should not return from the function.
 */
function getMovieTitles(substr) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        https.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=spiderman&page=1', (res) =>{
           // var {statusCode} = res;
            //var contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

            console.log('res---->', res);
        })
    })


}
```

Comment: Your code never resolves or rejects your promise.  Promises are merely notification systems.  They don't auto-detect anything with asynchronous operations.  They have to be told when to resolve or reject by your code.  You also have no error handling so if there's an error, you won't report it.

Comment: Plus, your `console.log('res---->', res);` has nothing to do with the surrounding promise.  That's just a plain callback there.  If you have code attempting to use the returned promise, then the promise will never get resolved as explained earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go,

```
   new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      https.get('your_url_here', (res) =>{
            // var {statusCode} = res;
            // var contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

            resolve(res);
        })
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log("Response",res);
    })
```

To Test Please Follow - https://jsfiddle.net/qdjkreo5/3741/

Alternatives :

You can deal with the data returned by https module in its callback itself as https also returns a callback.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('response', res);

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Apart from that To Combine REST API calls with JavaScript Promises in node.js you can make use of the npm module `request-promise`.

```
var request = require('request-promise');

request({
  "method":"GET", 
  "uri": "https://api.github.com/",
  "json": true,
  "headers": {
    "User-Agent": "My little demo app"
  }
}).then(console.log, console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the prior answers, here's a promise framework that handles both resolve (response, but not necessarily 200) and reject (no response).  The [axios](http://zetcode.com/javascript/axios/) package does this but hides the details.  I like this a little better because it gives me more control over the logic.

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  https.get(url, (res) => {
    let {statusCode} = res;
    let contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
    resolve(`status=${statusCode} type=${contentType}`);  // response, so resolve
  }).on('error', (err) => {
    reject(err);  // no response, so reject
  });
});

p1.then(res => console.log(`${url}: ${res}`))    // resolve
    .catch(err => console.log(err))              // reject
    .finally(console.log('Finally'));            // always
```

Test on the following URLs,

- https://google.com
- https://x.com
- http://x.com